# Split specific items in list into two

Tags: python, string, list, xml-parsing

I'm building an XML parser in python for an SVG file.  It will eventually become specific instructions for stepper motors.

SVG files contain commands such as 'M', 'C' and 'L.'  The path data might look like this:

[M199.66, 0.50C199.6, 0.50...0.50Z]

When I extracted the path data, it's a list of one item (which is a string).  I split the long string into multiple strings:

[u'M199.6', u'0.50C199.66', u'0.50']

The 'M, C and L' commands are important - I'm having difficulty splitting '0.5C199.6' into '0.5' and 'C199.6' because it only exists for certain items in the list, and I'd like to retain the C and not discard it.  This is what I have so far:

```
for item in path_strings[0]:
    s=string.split(path_strings[0], ',')
    print s
    break
for i in range(len(s)):
    coordinates=string.split(s[i],'C')
    print coordinates
    break
```

Comment: add the C back in where it should be?

Comment: Not clear with your requirements, but would suggest using regex `re` module instead of these string operations

Comment: svg.path can parse SVG paths. I think there's some bug in it if I remember correctly, but it is a start at least. :) https://github.com/regebro/svg.path

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try breaking it into substrings like this:

```
whole = "0.5C199.66"
start = whole[0:whole.find("C")]
end = whole[whole.find("C"):]
```

That should give you `start == "0.5"` and `end == "C199.66"`

Alternatively you could use the index function instead of find, which raises a ValueError when the substring can't be found.  That would give you the benefit of easily determining that for the current string, no 'C' command is present.

http://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string-functions

Comment: Instead of `string.find(whole,"C")`, you should just do `whole.find('C')`. There is absolutely no need to import `string`.

Answer (score 0):

Use a regex to search for the commands (`[MCL]`).

```
import re

lst = [u'M199.6', u'0.50C199.66', u'0.50']

for i, j in enumerate(lst):
    m = re.search('(.+?)([MCL].+)', j)
    if m:
        print [m.group(1), m.group(2)] #  = coordinates from your example
        lst[i:i+1] = [m.group(1), m.group(2)] # replace the item in the lst with the splitted thing
        # or do something else with the coordinates, whatever you want.

print lst
```

splits your list in:

```
[u'M199.6', u'0.50', u'C199.66', u'0.50']
```